# Правильная транслитерация

Tags: алгоритм

> Задача:
>   Сервер каждый день получает список данных, который содержит ФИО, город, индекс и адрес на латинице. Цель -> транслитерировать.

Подумаешь, задача, первое, что в голову пришло - это Яндекс переводчик. Всё классно, русские имена, города и адреса, всё зашибись работает, но это не транслит а перевод: например, имя Said переводит как "Сказал" вместо "Саид". Поэтому создал функцию фильтр, которая перед отправкой на яндекс транслитерирует определенные слова, например: (Said->Саид, flat->кв., St=>ул. и т.д.). Но список не заканчивается, всё расширяется и расширяется. (

И еще, слова на латинице пишутся разными, например, улица Пушкинский могут быть St. Pushkinskiy,St. Pushkinskii,St. Puschkinski St. Puschkinsky. И это пример только на окончание "ский" и буква "ш". И яндекс таких слов просто не переводит.

В общем, всё не АЙС.

Функция типа:

```
strtr($text,array(a=>a,b=>б ...))
```

тут пока бессильна, так как это функция имя Tatyana транслитерирует как Татыана, а не Татьяна, в лучшем случае Татяна, если сделать `strtr($text, array(ya=>я,...))`, нужно море правил, правил для "Ь", "Ъ", чтоб их правильно вставлять.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, может, есть сервис, который всё грамотно транслитерирует или ошибки исправляет. Неужели придется изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Спасибо всем за советы.

Answer (score 2):

Есть некая библиотека - RUtils. Там есть модуль транслитерации.

> И еще, слова на латинице пишутся разными, например улица Пушкинский могут быть St. Pushkinskiy,St. Pushkinskii,St. Puschkinski St. Puschkinsky. И это пример только на окончание "ский" и буква "ш".

В такой ситуации, например с окончаниями можно смотреть определенные префиксы и делать предположения, а в общем случае конечно нужно пользоваться расстояниями Левенштейна и Хэмминга.

Answer (score 1):

Я когда-то, лет десять назад, писал подобный велосипед (правда, на чистых сях). Он декодировал текст в транслите и переводил в читаемый русский. 100% качества перевода не получалось (не все умеют писать транслитом нормально), но текст был читаемый и имел только мелкие огрехи (обычно это были ошибки самого пишущего).

Суть кода. Вначале заменяем по таблице. Но таблица не просто, она зависит от предыдущих и последующих символов. К примеру, `y` может быть как `и`, так и `ы` - для этого нужно посмотреть предыдущий символ.

У меня просто были правила пошире. Там даже по полслова было. :)

Answer (score 0):

Привет,

**0.1 Написать свое**

Если задача стоит провести транслитерацию только для русского языка,
то унивирсальный способ - это составить словарик для каждой буквы алфавита и разбивать каждую строковую перменную на отдельные символы.

Пример из [transliterate](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/transliterate) библиотеки для Python

```html
mapping = (
    u"abvhgdezyijklmnoprstuf'ABVHGDEZYIJKLMNOPRSTUF'",
    u"абвгґдезиійклмнопрстуфьАБВГҐДЕЗИІЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЬ",
)
reversed_specific_mapping = (
    u"ьЬ",
    u"''"
)
pre_processor_mapping = {
    u"ye": u"є",
    u"zh": u"ж",
    u"yi": u"ї",
    u"kh": u"х",
    u"ts": u"ц",
    u"ch": u"ч",
    u"sh": u"ш",
    u"shch": u"щ",
    u"ju": u"ю",
    u"ja": u"я",
    u"Ye": u"Є",
    u"Zh": u"Ж",
    u"Yi": u"Ї",
    u"Kh": u"Х",
    u"Ts": u"Ц",
    u"Ch": u"Ч",
    u"Sh": u"Ш",
    u"Shch": u"Щ",
    u"Ju": u"Ю",
    u"Ja": u"Я"
}
```

**0.2 Ссылки**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9
- github.com barseghyanartur/transliterate
- wiki/GOST_16876-71

Answer (score 0):

Если есть контроль к тому, как происходит кодирование кириллицы в транслит, то можно попробовать какой-то обратимый транслит.

[https://программирование-по-русски.рф/яролит.яргт/](https://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82.%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%82/)

Транслитерация по ГОСТ 16876-71, таблица 2, но изменено так, чтобы слова превращались в слова, без знаков препинания. Т.е. ь = q, ъ = jq, а также возможность закодировать любые символы unicode, если они вдруг попадутся. Пример с сайта:

```
В чащах юга жил бы цитрус? Да, но фальшивый экземпляр!
Ъ '†'☭♥☼ 
XEROX, мир!
```

превратится в

```
V chashhakh juga zhil by citrus? Da, no falqshivyjj ehkzempljar!
JQ 'xu2020x'xu262dxxu2665xxu263cx 
xeXXEROXX, xrmir!
```

по этим правилом имя пользователя, e-mail, идентификатор Си в кириллице превратится в аналог в латинице. Код преобразования есть на JavaScript, он доступен по F12 или на 
https://bitbucket.org/budden/ppr/src/master/static/jarolit/%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82.js

Если доступа к кодированию нет, то вряд ли задачу получится решить правильно, потому что все популярные способы транслитерации неоднозначны - по латинице нельзя восстановить обратно кириллицу. Для исправления ошибок понадобится словарь, знающий все имена, города и адреса. С адресами ещё ничего, а вот имена можно подобрать такие, что любой раскодировщик ошибётся (Китай, тюркоязычные, фамилии разные заковыристые).